# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape into sklearn score()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe (`x_test`) of shape `(1672, 9376)` and its object is:

```
<1672x9376 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 14108 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I am trying to pass this data into sklearn's `score()` method against from labeling data like so:

`classifier.score(x_test, y_test)`

But I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (1672)
```

My `y_test` is of shape `(1672,)`

`x_test` contents

```
(Pdb) self.x_test[1,1]
0.0
(Pdb) self.x_test[1,2]
0.0
(Pdb) self.x_test[1,:]
<1x9376 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but three things that might help: 1. post an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), 2. post the full stack trace, 3. post which classifier you are using.

Comment: What `sklearn`, `numpy`, `scipy` versions do you have?